# Cannot read property 'query' of null in react js

Tags: reactjs, pagination

i have applied pagination in react-redux process, and trying to get query parameter in "mapStateToProps" function but getting below error - 
calling browser url is  - http://localhost:3000/blog-list?page_no=1

[image]

here is my component's code snippet -

```
import React from 'react'; 
import StaticLayout from '../Layout/StaticLayout';
import { getBlogList } from '../actions/signupActions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 

import { Pagination } from 'react-bootstrap'; 
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'; 


class BlogList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        document.title = "Blogs";

        this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getBlogList();
    }

    render(){

        //===pagination variable========
        const per_page = 1;
        let pages = 0;
        if(this.props.blogListData !== undefined){
            pages = Math.ceil(this.props.blogListData.count / per_page) ;
        } 
        const current_page = this.props.page;
        const start_offset = (current_page - 1) * per_page;
        let start_count = 0;
        //===End pagination variable========


        return(
            <StaticLayout>
                <html content with require list />
                <Pagination className="users-pagination pull-right" bsSize="medium" maxButtons={10} first last next prev boundaryLinks items={pages} activePage={current_page} onSelect={this.changePage} />

            </StaticLayout>
        );  
    }

    changePage(page){
        this.props.dispatch(push('/?page_no='+page))
    }


}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return { 
        blogListData: state.UserReducer.blogData,
        page: Number(state.routing.locationBeforeTransitions.query.page_no) || 1,
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return bindActionCreators({getBlogList: getBlogList}, dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (BlogList);
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong, because in console you can see its giving up to routing.locationBeforeTransitions. not 'query'..

Comment: `this.props.dispatch(push('/?page_no='+page))` should be different. Query params do not have trailing `/`

Comment: @ved , error is related to "mapStateToProps()" where i am returing 'page' . I didn't understand what do you want to say.

Comment: Replace `Number(state.routing.locationBeforeTransitions.query.page_no) || 1` with `state.routing && state.routing.locationBeforeTransitions && state.routing.locationBeforeTransitions.query && state.routing.locationBeforeTransitions.query.page_no || 1`

Comment: yes its works thanks #Glenn , but when i am clicking on "2" next pagination link its giving error - >>>> `this.props.dispatch is not a function`

Comment: And, I think its not picking value from query string, its always picking 1 from or condition....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure `React-router-redux` to be able to use `state.routing.locationBeforeTransitions.query.page_no‌​`. However there are other ways to do it.

If you are using React-router v4, which I am assuming

You need to make use a separate library that supports query parsing, since its support was withdrawn from react-router v4

You can make use of **[`query-string` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string)**

You can get the data like

```
import queryString from 'query-string'

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
    var queryParam = queryString.parse(ownProps.location.search);
    return { 
        blogListData: state.UserReducer.blogData,
        page: Number(queryParam.get('page_no') || 1,
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help Atul :)