# Within mapStateToProps, how to obtain a react-router param?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I have the following URL: `http://localhost:4400/skills/3`

In my react component I then have:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { skill_id: props.match.params.skill_id };
  }

....

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    skill_id: state.skill_id,
    ratingsBySkillId: state.rating.by_skill_id.find(el => el.skill_id === skill_id)
  };
};
```

The problem is `state.skill_id` is not available in mapStateToProps? Why? How can I use params in mapStateToProps?

Comment: Check this answer as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44673079/cannot-read-property-query-of-null-in-react-js/44674408#44674408

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri has answered it very well in the above link. Refer to that, that's the right solution

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This ended up working:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const skill_id = ownProps.match.params.skill_id;
....
```

Answer (score 2):

so what you would want to do is map skill_id in mapStateToProps to the value that is stored in the state from react-router. Then you would just bring in skill_id

Also I would recommend some logic just to check if skill_id is undefined as that key only is generated in the object if the user has a value for the `skill_id`

```
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { skill_id: props.skill_id };
}

....

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
     skill_id: (('skill_id' in state.routing.locationBeforeTransitions.query) ? state.routing.locationBeforeTransitions.query.skill_id: false),
     ratingsBySkillId: state.rating.by_skill_id.find(el => el.skill_id === skill_id)
  };
};
```

Hopefully that helps but your value should be in the routing object of the state

Answer (score 1):

If your using react router, just use `this.props.params.id.`

this depends on how you defined the router though. if your router is like

```
<route path = `/skills/:id` component = {yourComponent} />
```

then it works.
but if your router is like

```
<route path = `/skills/:number` component = {yourComponent} />
```

then you have to do `this.props.params.number`

Comment: `this` is not defined in `const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {`

Comment: I Must have mis understood your question, Do you want the id from the URL?
    http://localhost:4400/skills/3 
in this case 3?
or are you storing the id in the redux store?